# UIwebview losing css3/html formatting

Tags: iphone, html, ios, uiwebview, formatting

What I'm trying to do is get certain part/section of a webpage and showing in my UIWebView.

The part am trying to show has some input fields and a submit button. When I display the extracted part using a UIWebview. Am losing all the formatting. The spaces etc details are lost.

I downloaded that html page to my computer and modified it ( removed unnecessary parts) manually and it works fine on computer.

Here is my sample Code. Looked at other related questions to no avail.

```
-(IBAction)showContactPage {

NSString *urlContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"wwww.example.com/contact.html"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];

[myWebView loadHTMLString:urlContents baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/"]];
}

//WebView Delegate method

 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

 NSString *urlContents = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('column')[0].innerHTML"]; 

 NSString *headContents = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.head.innerHTML"];

 urlContents = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head>%@</head><body>%@</body></html>",headContents,urlContents];

 [myWebView loadHTMLString:urlContents baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/"]];

 [self.view addSubview:myWebView];
```

}

Let me know if am missing out something on UIwebview.

Comment: Its your real code skiping webViewDidFinishLoad for the already modificated string?

Comment: I first load webview with contact page and in the delegate method webView finish loading , I use stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString and extract required parts of contact page and again load the webview with newly extracted HTML.

Comment: This newly extracted html did trigger webviewfinishload on delegate again?

Comment: Yes Cram. it calls webviewfinishload again. Am using an if statement to differentiate both. 

I dint mention here just to keep it simple

Comment: Ok, seems correct, maybe doctype or charset issues? Good luck joker ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out where it went wrong. The stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method is returning us what is there inside of it and not the attributes of it and thus we are losing the formatting
viz. in my case following piece of code is not returning attributes of tag having 'column' as class name

```
urlContents = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('column')[0].innerHTML"];
```

this was not returning `<div id="left" class="column">` and thus i was losing the formatting/styling